# Problem with returning booleans from C++ to JavaScript using v8 JS engine

Tags: javascript, c++, macos, v8

I am trying to embed v8 static libs into my standalone C++ application ( macOS: Monterey 12.6, CPU: Intel Core i7, Xcode: 13.1 (13A1030d) )

1. I've written a simple bash script to get v8 static libs:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=$PWD/depot_tools:$PATH

mkdir v8
cd v8
fetch v8
cd v8

git checkout branch-heads/9.4
gclient sync

gn gen out/x64.release--args='
is_component_build = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_goma = false
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_enable_disassembler = true
v8_enable_object_print = true
v8_enable_verify_heap = true
dcheck_always_on = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false'

ninja -C out/x64.release v8_monolith
```

2. copy libv8_monolith.a, libv8_libplatform.a, libv8_libbase.a from out/x64.release/obj to my xcode c++ console project's folder and link them to it.
3. the c++ part of test project looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>

#include <v8.h>
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>

using namespace v8;

std::string ToStdString(v8::Isolate *isolate, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> valueMaybe);

bool LoadScript(const std::string& path, Isolate* _isolate, Local<Context> _context);

void LogCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args);

void CreateTrue(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    v8::Isolate *isolate(args.GetIsolate());
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::True(isolate));
}

void CreateFalse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    v8::Isolate *isolate(args.GetIsolate());
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::False(isolate));
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    
    V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    V8::Initialize();
    
    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
    
    Local<Context> context;
    {
        Locker l(isolate);
        Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
        
        Local<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
        
        global->Set(isolate, "log", FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, LogCallback));
        
        global->Set(isolate, "cpp_CreateTrue", FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, CreateTrue));
        global->Set(isolate, "cpp_CreateFalse", FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, CreateFalse));
        
        context = Context::New(isolate,  nullptr, global);
        
        auto jsLikeBool = v8::Boolean::New(isolate, true);
        // at this point typeof this jsLikeBool equals to string, but should be equal to boolean
        if (jsLikeBool->IsBoolean()) {
            std::cout << "c++::GetBoolean jsLikeBoolean has boolean type" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "c++::GetBoolean jsLikeBoolean DOES NOT have boolean type, but HAS: " << ToStdString(isolate, jsLikeBool->TypeOf(isolate)) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    if (!LoadScript(std::filesystem::current_path() / "assets" / "bools.js", isolate, context)) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    isolate->Dispose();
    V8::Dispose();
    V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
    return 0;
}
```

4. assets/bools.js file:

```
const Js_CreateTrue = () => true;
const Js_CreateFalse = () => false;

const CheckCreator = function(tag, getter, expectedType, expectedValue) {
    const value = getter();
    const valueType = typeof value;
    
    if (valueType !== expectedType) {
        log(`JS::test ${tag} failed types check, actual: ${valueType}, but expected: ${expectedType}`);
    }
        
    if (value !== expectedValue) {
        log(`JS::test ${tag} failed values check, actual: ${value}, but expected: ${expectedValue}`);
    }
}

CheckCreator("Js_CreateTrue", Js_CreateTrue, "boolean", true); // OK
CheckCreator("Js_CreateFalse", Js_CreateFalse, "boolean", false); // OK

CheckCreator("cpp_CreateTrue", cpp_CreateTrue, "boolean", true); // FAILED: gets an empty string
CheckCreator("cpp_CreateFalse", cpp_CreateFalse, "boolean", false); // causes crash in c++, actual type is `symbol`
```

I have already tried different tags/branches of v8 sources, nothing helps.
How to get rid of such strange behaviour with returning booleans from C++ to JS?

Comment: What is this *such strange behaviour with returning booleans*?

Comment: @273K
I am exposing from C++ to JS the function which returns _true_: `args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::True(isolate));`

Then I call it in JS and get an empty string as returned value from it

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and JS code

Comment: in C++:
`void CreateTrue(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    v8::Isolate *isolate(args.GetIsolate());
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::True(isolate));
}
`
Its using in JS:`
`const trueValue = cpp_CreateTrue();
log(`type: ${typeof trueValue}, value: ${trueValue}`); // prints: type: string, value:`

Comment: Sorry, did not see JS in the question in a mobile. Now see it on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro the same symptoms you're seeing, but maybe close enough...

First off, I'm somewhat annoyed by the fact that the example code is incomplete. What on earth was the point of the edit where you dropped the bodies of `LoadScript` and the other helper functions? Are you trying to make it difficult to help you?

You also left out one crucial step, which is how exactly you compiled your embedding application. My first guess was that you may have an inconsistency in where the `-DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS` flag is passed; but on closer investigation that's probably not the problem, because that would have resulted in a very hard-to-miss error message on startup, even with a version as old as 9.4.
That said, there's a number of other inconsistencies that could be happening there. For example, you only said that you're copying the compiled libraries, you didn't confirm that you're #including the `v8.h` from the checkout.

When I try your code (restored from before it was edited out), I see `c++::GetBoolean jsLikeBoolean has boolean type` as expected.

However, I'm getting a segfault after that message. The following sequence is a bug:

```
Local<Context> context;
{
  HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  context = Context::New(...);
}
LoadScript(..., context);
```

When the HandleScope goes out of scope, it destroys all handles created in it, which includes `context`. The fix is to perform the `LoadScript` call while the HandleScope is still alive. Or turn `context` into a `v8::Global`.

---

Side notes:

- `GetNewContext` doesn't do what it says. In its current form, it only creates a new handle for the existing context, which serves no purpose. (Creating an `EscapableHandleScope` just for returning one single handle is also rather pointless. That'd only be useful if there was a non-trivial number of temporary handles that could legitimately go out of scope when the helper function returns.)
- When starting a new project in 2023, I wouldn't use a JS engine from 2021.
- Your `v8_enable_*` build flags are surprising. Do you really want debugging features in a non-debug build? A good set of build flag is what you get when you follow [the documentation](https://v8.dev/docs/embed#run-the-example):

```
dcheck_always_on = false
is_component_build = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"  # Or "arm64" if that's your hardware.
use_custom_libcxx = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
# As of V8 10.8, if you don't want to bother building sandboxing
# support into your embedder:
v8_enable_sandbox = false
```

- With up-to-date V8 versions, your code will need a few minor adaptations: `ShutdownPlatform` is now called `DisposePlatform`, and the `ScriptOrigin` constructor takes an `Isolate*` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I will look at the whole question carefully a bit later. As for the specific question in the title see bellow.

`v8::ReturnValue<T>` has a member function `void Set(bool value)`. The right way to set a boolean to a return value is

```
void CreateFalse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(false);
}

void CreateTrue(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(true);
}
```

Comment: That's a convenient shortcut, not the only "right way". What the OP does should work as well.

Comment: It does not change anything.
The problem still exists even if I do:
`args.GetReturnValue().Set(true);`

Comment: @AlexMay I compiled your code with the removed parts. It works well, no outputs, no crashes. Added `else` to the last `if` in your script and got `JS::test Js_CreateTrue value: true
JS::test Js_CreateFalse value: false
JS::test cpp_CreateTrue value: true
JS::test cpp_CreateFalse value: false`

Comment: Can you please share how did you get v8 libs? Did you build it using my script? I think that my problem is in it.

Comment: @AlexMay `brew install v8`